# from PyBioMed.PyMolecule import moe; ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rdkit'

Tags: python, conda, miniconda, rdkit

I tried to install the pybiomed package by using [this link](https://github.com/gadsbyfly/PyBioMed):

1- Download the PyBioMed-1.0.zip

2- Extract the PyBioMed-1.0.zip file

3- cd PyBioMed-1.0

4-`python setup.py install`

Then I found out I need to install the rdkit package too. Based on [this](https://www.rdkit.org/docs/Install.html) document I need to use conda while I have installed standalone python 3.6.8, so I installed miniconda then downgrade its python to 3.6.8 version and used the below command to install the Rdkit and successfully finished:

```py
conda install -c conda-forge rdkit
```

Now, when I use this `from PyBioMed.PyMolecule import moe`, I get this  `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rdkit'`! May you help me how to declare, show or clarify the basic python that you can find Rdkit in conda's path?

Let me add the following points:

A- I am using the Windows 10.

B- I have added the below lines to the system path:

```
C:\Program Files\Python36\
C:\Program Files\Python36\Scripts\
C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3
C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\Lib\site-packages
C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin
C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\Library\usr\bin
C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\Library\bin
C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\Scripts
```

Comment: I think you need to walk us through the exact steps you took. Did you create a separate conda environment to install rdkit?

Comment: The outputs of `which conda`, `which python`, and `conda list` would also be helpful. +1 to installing everything into a separate conda environment (this would go between steps 3 and 4)

Comment: @OliverScott Actually, I did not create an environment. Because I did consider it a necessary step